# Unity3D - Why is a variable always true despite what I set on the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have set a variable as SerializeField to choose the value from the inspector. However, the value is not changing and it has always a "true" value.

I've tried making it public, changing the name, re importing the component, resetting the component, ... And nothing seems to make any effect, the only thing that is working is changing the value at the Awake method.

```
public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private bool playSoundsAtColision; //WHY IS TRUE??? Is false in the inspector...

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (this.playSoundsAtColision)
            Debug.Log("playSoundsAtColision = " + this.playSoundsAtColision + " by: " + gameObject.name, gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here you have an image of the whole code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyut6.png
(where you can see that the variable only is declared, then checked and printed and there is no other access to it anywhere else)

Here what happens despite what I set on the inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBz7g.png

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Firstly, you should include your code in your question not as an image.  Secondly, reviewing the image I cannot see your whole code as literally all your functions are closed(Click the + on the left of the function to open it up) except one, and we cannot see the end of that function.  So no-one can help you with what you provided.   I have a suspicion that your awake method is setting it to false, therefore it doesn't matter what you put in the inspector.

Comment: I also see that you did a search on that variable however, I have no idea when that search result came up, or what parameters you used to perform that search.  Have you tried just rewriting the script with as a different component and seeing if you have the same results?  (So making an AudioController2 class instead, as this would help us understand if it is a serialization issue)

Comment: If it's working in Awake() method then why not to set bool value to false then change it in inspector to true whenever you need it? </b>

Comment: - Since you are using 'this' keyword you should also track the instance of the class (maybe that is causing the problem, I am not sure tho) </b>
- Make sure you are not changing the value in other scripts

Comment: @Gray_Rhino typically if it is a private data member, and if his variable is only referenced in those 3 places in this script, then the odds of another script changing the value are unlikely.  Which is why in my comment I mention we don't know what parameters for the reference search were, or when that reference search was done.  If he sets the value to false in awake, then changing it in the inspector will make no difference, which is the reason I also pointed out we cannot see what code is in his methods per his screenshot.

Comment: @OP you should also include a screenshot of your objects components(All of them) and change your debugging statement to state the objects name that is having the issue.  Also if only 1 instance of this script should be allowed per object, you can add the `DisallowMultipleComponent` attribute.

Comment: @Eddge Here you have the code: https://github.com/guplem/Proj2/blob/feature/sound/Proj2/Assets/Scripts/Controllers/AudioController.cs I thought that this was not necessary because the variable is only used in those lines that I wrote in the question. The search is done by references so if anything uses that variable it should be shown at the reference search. I also did a search by name and I got the same result. In the Awake method the variable is not modified. However, if I change the value on the awake the value changes as expected, but if I comment it and I use the inspector it does not.

Comment: Can you try and add the attribute I mention above, I just want to rule out the possibility of multiple of these scripts being on the same gameObject, or try and make a new `AudioController` script but as `AudioControllerTest` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! This was what caused that behaviour. I checked that the prefab didn't have two repeated components but the prefab variant had. Sorry, I still getting used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the component existed multiple times.

I checked that the prefab didn't have two repeated components but the prefab variant had. I'm still getting used to it.

As AresCaelum said, using the "DisallowMultipleComponent" attribute should help to avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1. You're hanging the property while the game runs in standalone - when you exit standalone, properties get reset
2. You didn't set the property in you code. To change a default of a boolean (true), you need to set a value to the field playSoundsAtColision:

   ```
   public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour 
   {

       [SerializeField] public bool playSoundsAtColision = false; //you just shoud change the variable to public and default value to false or true

       private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
       {
           if (this.playSoundsAtColision)
               Debug.Log("playSoundsAtColision = " + this.playSoundsAtColision + " by: " + gameObject.name, gameObject);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Um, your code has no need of the SerializeField attribute, since a public variable in Unity automatically gets serialized(If it is serializable which a bool is).  Not to mention a private serialized field gets initialized without having to set a default value.  OP mentioned he already tried #2 of your suggestions.  so #1 should really just be a comment and not an answer.